# How to set the back arrow of the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, storyboard

When I push from view controller1 to view controller2, there seems no back button item on the view controller2's navigation bar.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The result of `vc2`:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

How to set that in storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

If you are pushing view controller from VC1 to VC2 through navigation controller then write below line in VC2's viewWillAppear method.

If you are using **Swift 3.0 :**

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false

 self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated:true);
```

Comment: No, I means how to set my vc2's navigation bar back item.

Comment: write above code in VC2's viewWillAppear method. You can see back button on VC2's navigation bar which will redirect to VC1 once it is clicked

Comment: You do not need to set back item bar buttton in storyboard. as it will be shown once once it is pushed. you can check it on device

Answer (score 0):

I see your Controller1's navigation bar have left bar button item and right bar button item.

You can drag a button item to your VC2's navigation item.

[image]